# Expresiones regulares, bloque de comentarios

Tags: java, regex

Llevo unas horitas intentando hacer una expresión regular que me trae loco... A ver si me podéis ayudar, por favor. Primero el código:

```java
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Ejercicio2_1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String codeJava = 
        "public class Ejercicio1_Math {\r\n" + 
        "\r\n" + 
        "   public static void main(String[] args) {\r\n" + 
        "       \r\n" + 
        "       //  MATH\r\n" + 
        "       \r\n" + 
        "   /*\r\n" + 
        "    * 1. static float abs(float a)\r\n" + 
        "    * 2. static int addExact(int x, int y)\r\n" + 
        "    * 3. static double ceil (double a). Probar con positivo y negativo.\r\n" + 
        "    * 4. static int decrementExact (int a)\r\n" + 
        "    * 5. static double floor(double a). Probar con positivo y negativo.\r\n" + 
        "    * 6. static int incrementExact(int a)\r\n" + 
        "    * 7. static double max(double a, double b)\r\n" + 
        "    * 8. static int multiplyExact(int x, int y)\r\n" + 
        "    * 9. static int negateExact (int a)\r\n" + 
        "    */\r\n" + 
        "\r\n" + 
        "       float var_float;\r\n" + 
        "       int var_int;\r\n" + 
        "       double var_double;\r\n" + 
        ";

        commentOfOneLine(codeJava);
    }

    public static void commentOfOneLine(String string) {

        int count = 0;

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("/\\*.*\\*/");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

        while(matcher.find()) {
            count++;

            System.out.printf("Coincidencia número %d: empieza en %d y termina en %d\n", count, matcher.start(), matcher.end()-1);
        }
```

Necesito extraer el índice de dónde empieza y termina cada bloque de código.

Creo que el problema está en que el .* lo coge todo y no me deja coger la última parte. */. Y no sé cómo excluir eso de la búsqueda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por lo que he podido probar de esta manera puedes buscar con Pattern código comentado multilinea:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("/\\*" + "[\\s\\S]" + "*?\\*/");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
```

Y con este código comentado solo en una linea:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("//[^\r\n]*");
```

Podrías probar en combinar los dos y mostrar los resultados en el system.print.format.

Espero que te sirva de ayuda.

Comment: Buenas y gracias.

He probado la respuesta que me has dado, pero me da cerca de 200 comprobaciones y solo debería darme una en ese códgio.

Necesito que la expresión regular me diga dónde empieza el bloque de comentarios y dónde termina.

Estoy tan saturado que creo que me he liado al redactar la pregunta.

Necesito que me diga el índice dónde comienza el /* y dónde acaba */.

Perdón por la confusión y gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: He modificado la respuesta y espero que te sirva de ayuda. Me comentas como te ha ido. Y no te preocupes que con los regex me doy cabezazos contra la pared también.